# BIM Viewer Markup - Can we edit saved markups or is it only supports view?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Can we edit saved markups which we draw on a viewer?
Does it only support view using restoreState and loadMarkups functions?

Or is there anyway I can update the created and saved markups as my functionality requires reviewer User should be able to update this markups.

```
var markupsPersist = markup.generateData()
// current view state (zoom, direction, sections)
var viewerStatePersist = markup.viewer.getState()
// finish edit of markup
markup.leaveEditMode()
// hide markups (and restore Viewer tools)
markup.hide()

// restore the view to the state where the markups were created
markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist)
// show markups
markup.show();
// show the markups on a layer
markup.loadMarkups(markupsPersist, "layerName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can access the markups via `markupExt.markups` and for example you can edit the text markup with below:

```
const textMarkup = markupExtension.markups[0]; //access the existing markups via markupExtensionObject.markups
textMarkup.setText('new text');
markupExtension.leaveEditMode();
markupExtension.enterEditMode() //be sure to re-enter edit mode for the changes to take effect
```

Comment: This is not clear to me. Actually my requirement is if we already saved a markup, can we restore and edit it? if yes, can you give me an example. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this this scenario too and you can edit a saved markup.  You may need to store your markup state to your own database to be accessed and restored later by the Reviewer. Here is a sample that shows this functionality.

https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948

Here is blog post discussing this as well. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/high-performance-3d-markups-pointcloud-forge-viewer